# Table doesnt created in Spring Boot H2

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, h2

im trying to connect H2 to my MVC Spring boot application and the connection between the H2 and the application is working, but there is no Table created in the H2 Console.

**i have tried to add ScanEntity("Package name")** above the main class and nothing happaned.

**application.properties:**
[image]

**Bean Entity:**
[image]

**my pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**and there is no Table in H2 Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:
i changed the hierarchy of packages to be like this:
all the packages would be under another package different from Java:
[image]